# Create ggplot bar chart including categories with no observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

The minimal R script below produces the expected barplot, also shown.

I would like to include categories with no observations, 1 and 3 in this example, these bars would have zero height but the width occupied would be the same as a bar for non-zero height.

Numerous experiments with `labs <- as.character(seq(0,4)); p <- p+scale_x_discrete(breaks=labs, labels=labs)` with and without `drop=FALSE` do not generate (for me) the bar plot with zero height bars for the no observation items and the x axis labelled accordingly.

What is a good way to achieve the desired bar plot?

(R version 3.6.2, ggplot version 3.2.1.)

```
require(ggplot2)
mdf <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,2,0,0,4))
p <- ggplot(mdf)+geom_bar(aes(x=x))
print(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Several hours later...I now have a solution involving creating an extra column of type factor.

```
require(ggplot2)
mdf <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,2,0,0,4))
xlev <- seq(0,4)
mdf$xf <- factor(mdf$x, levels=xlev)
p <- ggplot(mdf)+geom_bar(aes(x=xf))
p <- p+scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
print(p)
```

[image]